# What is the collective noun for a group of giraffes?

Tags: collective-nouns

My son's primary school teacher has written

> A *kaleidoscope* of giraffes

But [elsewhere](http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Pointless/AnimalGroups.html) I see  a *tower* of giraffes.  And yet [elsewhere again](https://www.shentonsafaris.com/blog/a-confusion-of-giraffes/) I see *journey* and few others.

Comment: This source lists "tower": https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/word-lists/list-of-names-for-groups-of-animals.html

Comment: And so does this one: https://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/animals/blogs/99-strange-collective-animal-names

Comment: Note that "kaleidoscope" is a way of describing their appearance (imagine the spots moving this way and that) -- it's not necessarily implying that that is an "official" term.

Comment: My quick search came up with tower, herd, corps, journey, totter, and kaleidoscope.  But by far the most prevalent was "tower".  And herd seems to be used by some African conservation groups.  kaleidoscope showed up with the lowest frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about looking at the statistics?

I searched the [iWeb corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/iweb/) for `_nn* of giraffes`, where the first item matches nouns. Looking at the most relevant nouns, I see these numbers of results for each:

- herd: 44*
- tower: 22*
- herds: 17
- group: 17*
- family: 16
- groups: 6
- kaleidoscope: 2*
- menagerie: 1
- flock: 1

*Includes sites that are listing terms for groups of giraffes

(I suggest looking at the results yourself; it’s easy.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer Laurel.  I took your advice and looked at the results myself.  What an amazing and powerful tool.  

I'm accepting your answer because I found these **stats** slightly more helpful (only by a whisker) than the **explanation** in @No Name's answer which was also very good.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on here is that the teacher is engaging in the game of venery, which is just a fancy way of saying "making up names for groups of animals". This is why a pack of lions is a pride and flock of crows is a murder.

For the most part, these terms of venery have no traction in the scientific community. The only exception is the pride of lions - almost nobody calls it a pack, I only did to make my point. Scientifically speaking, giraffes form herds (because they're grazing ungulates that aren't sheep).

That doesn't mean you can't call it a tower or a kaleidoscope of giraffes, even in scientific papers (I'm sure plenty of scientific papers have referred to murders of crows), but you have to be careful to specify the animal the first few times you use the term.

Comment: Thanks for this answer No Name.  It helped me to understand the **why** these multiple terms exist. Your answer is helpful as well as correct.  

However I can only accept one answer as correct (the most helpful one). I found the stats in @Laurel's answer more compelling in helping me choose. Sorry.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Kaleidoscope, tower, herd, troop, kindergarten and corps are all acceptable terminology to describe a group of giraffes. Source: https://africafreak.com/animal-group-names

Comment: Thanks for this answer ForeverLearning.  Like some of the other answers, it's also correct.  However I can only accept one answer as correct (the most helpful one), and I found the stats in @Laurel's answer more compelling in helping me choose. Sorry.